# Crystal report-VB6 set path to MySql server

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

Crystal report-> VB6 set path to mysql server 'CrystalReport1.DataFiles(0)' = ?
Any budy have idea how to set path ...

Comment: Converted to a comment for @ruby.lee: "What is the version of Crystal Report you are using? I use Crystal Report 10 with VB6+MySQL, I just use ODBC to link Crystal Report to MySQL, and use ADODB in VB6."